# recursively using the output as an input for a function

Tags: r

edit: this is a constant rebalanced portfolio problem.

Does anyone know what function to use for recursive calling?

let s= stock;

let c= cash;

let X_0= initial wealth;

let r = is a random vector looks like (1,-0.5,-0.5,1,-.5,1,1,1-0.5,...) #chance of getting 1 or 0.5 is each 50%.

X_0 = s+c

X_1 = 1/2*x_0*(1+r) + 1/2*x_0

X_2 = 1/2*x_1*(1+r) + 1/2*x_1   #in this equation x_0 is changed to x_1, that's all

X_3 = 1/2*x_2*(1+r) + 1/2*x_2
....
and so on,

Is there a function in R that takes input from last step as input for this step?

do.call? lapply? recall?  I couldn't figure it out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it's recursion you're after? This looks more like an AR process.

Comment: I am not sure if I have the correct term, maybe it is called AR?  I always thought that term is reserved for time series.

Answer (score 6):

Its a job tailor made for the higher order function `Reduce`. Here is the code

```
calc_wealth <- function(x, r){
  return(0.5*x*(1 + r) + 0.5*x)
}

x0 <- 10 
set.seed(1234) 
r  <- sample(c(-0.5, 1), size = 5, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))

wealth <- Reduce('calc_wealth', r, init = x0, accumulate = TRUE)

> r
[1]  1.0 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5
> wealth
[1] 10.000000 15.000000 11.250000  8.437500  6.328125  4.746094
```

Here is the appropriate documentation for `Reduce` extracted from the help file.

`Reduce(f, x, init, right = FALSE, accumulate = FALSE)`

> Reduce uses a binary function to successively combine the elements of
>   a given vector and a possibly given initial value. If init is given,
>   Reduce logically adds it to the start (when proceeding left to right)
>   or the end of x, respectively. If this possibly augmented vector v has
>   n > 1 elements, Reduce successively applies f to the elements of v
>   from left to right or right to left, respectively. I.e., a left reduce
>   computes l_1 = f(v_1, v_2), l_2 = f(l_1, v_3), etc., and returns
>   l_{n-1} = f(l_{n-2}, v_n),

Comment: hey, thanks, Ramnath, that's a pretty neat function.  short code, but seems like a lot stuff under the hood (the parameter and the algorithm).  Still trying to chew on it.  thanks again.

Comment: higher order functions are a little hard to chew on, but provide incredible power to abstract ideas. `github` seems to be down now, but @hadley has an incredible wiki page on how to use higher order functions. will post the link once `github` is back on.

Comment: @Ramnath -- github's up now, and the link is: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/First-class-functions .  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: great, thanks, I've been using his ggplot2() package. yes, please let me know if it is posted, I actually don't remember coming across it.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, thanks, this would come very handy, definitely collecting it into my bookmark. :)

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT:] OP clarified that `r` changes each loop and they want to avoid using a `for` loop.

In that case, you might try something like:

```
# generate vector of .5s and 1s with 50% probability of each.
# length N.
rs <- ifelse(runif(N)<.5,.5,1) 
x0 <- ... # set x0
x  <- x0
# loop over rs, evaluation a new x each time. Note the '<<-'
vapply( rs, function(r) x <<- 1/2*x*(1+r)+1/2*x, -1 )
x # contains final value after N iterations.
```

Remember `vapply` requires a third argument giving the return type of the function, and this speeds it up a little over `sapply` etc (do `?vapply`).

The meaning of the `<<-` is to modify the `x` in the *global* environment rather than within the scope of the function in `vapply`.

The usual caveats for messing around in other scopes apply (ie beware you don't modify `x` in some environment you didn't mean to).

---

You could achieve this with a `for` loop:

```
N = number of times to iterate the loop

x_0 <- s+c
x   <- x_0
for ( i in 1:N ) {
    # [calculate r here]
    # calculate x
    x <- 1/2*x*(1+r) + 1/2*x
}
```

However, your equation looks like it can be simplified to avoid all this:

```
x_{i+1} = 1/2 * x_i * (1+r) + 1/2 * x_i
        = 1/2 * x_i * (1+r +1)    
        = 1/2 * x_i * (2+r)
```

In that case, one can see that:

```
x_n = [1/2 * (2+r) ]^n * x_0
```

When you say that `r` is "not constant" do you mean it changes every time you calculate `x_i`? As in the `r` in the equation for `x_1` is not the same as the `r` in the equation for `x_2`? In that case you have to use a for loop and the simplified equation for `x_n` **isn't** valid.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, r changes every time.  I will modify that part on the post above. Actually, r=- 0.5 or r=1, there is a 50% probability of getting either one.

Comment: Then you can use the `for` loop, that will work (with the appropriate line that calculates r for the loop).

Comment: yes, I was actually trying to avoid that, since R already have functions such as lapply or tapply, that writes the for loops, but this case is a little different.

Comment: yes, here is a reproducible code for the variable r, hope this will clarify what I meant.
r = sample(c(-0.5,1), size=50, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.5))

Comment: Yep, I've updated my post to use built in-function `vapply`. Next post down is good too, although will be slower as `Reduce` is simply an R function with the for loop I described in it.

Comment: Vapply + global modification = horror.